# Spring MVC controller not invoked by Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

**Update:** Somehow, after another round of adjustments and redeployment, localhost:8080/ping-1.0/ping started working. Configuration files are still as below. I wish I knew what I fixed without knowing it, but it is solved now.

I've been wrestling with this for a couple days, tried all sorts of solutions I've seen here and elsewhere, and nothing has worked. I have a Spring MVC controller deployed in Tomcat, but can't access it.

Tools:

Spring 3.2.0
Tomcat 7
Java 1.6

Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class PingController {

@RequestMapping("/ping")
public String ping (Model model) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("ping ping ping");
    String s = (new Date()).toString();
    model.addAttribute("message", s);
    return "ping";
}
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ping</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class><init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/ping-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ping</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ping</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

ping-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="myclass.ping"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

The WAR file is called ping-1.0.war. Deployment seems to go fine. I see a directory called ping-1.0 in $CATALINA_BASE/webapps and this in catalina.log:

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/ping],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String myclass.ping.PingController.ping(org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception
```

Tomcat is running on port 8080. I can access localhost:8080/manager for instance. But localhost:8080/ping returns a 404 message from Tomcat. I see nothing in the logs other than a record of a GET request. No errors at all. I've tried a lot of variations of request mapping, URL filter, etc. and just can't get this to work.

Comment: You should add the name of the deployment context to the URL.  If you deployed foo.war, the URL would be http://localhost:8080/foo/ping.  So for you it's http://localhost:8080/ping-1.0/ping

Comment: Already tried-- didn't work.

Comment: what is the package in which the `PingController` is located

Comment: Weirdly, after another go-round, ping-1.0/ping started working.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have the context root on your URL and you actually need to have `/ping/ping` because both the dispatcher servlet and your ping controller are mapped to `/ping`.  Try this:

```
http://localhost:8080/ping-1.0/ping/ping
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you've got the dispatcher servlet also mapped to `/ping`, that means you've got to hit `/ping-1.0/ping/ping` to hit your ping controller - I updated my answer with the correct URL. As a side note, I would normally expect the dispatcher servlet to be mapped to something more broad like `/`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. breaking my head about this.. forgot the /app/* in the web.xml completely

Answer (score 3):

```
@RequestMapping("/ping")
```

Means `/ping` relative to the URL the dispatcher servlet listens on.

```
<url-pattern>/ping</url-pattern>
```

Here comes the problem. This makes your dispatcher servlet listen to one URL and one URL only. And that is assumingly `localhost:8080/ping-1.0/ping`. But your controller method is relative to that, so it would be `localhost:8080/ping-1.0/ping/ping`, and the disptacher servlet does not react on that URL. You have to use a pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/ping/*</url-pattern>
```

Now the dispatcher servlet can listen on all URLs **starting with** `localhost:8080/ping-1.0/ping`.

One final note: Depending on your configuration it could be that you have to omit `ping-1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've configured Spring incorrectly.

I'd expect the servlet to be Spring's dispatcher servlet, not your ping controller.  That's what figures out where to route the request.  You don't have a front controller servlet.

I could be thinking Spring 2.x and earlier.  I'll admit that I'd be incorrect if Spring 3.x changed the need for the dispatcher.  But that's the way my applications are set up.